# How can I (programmatically) get Azure Blob maximum allowed size?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the **maximum** allowed size for an Azure Blob? Also for a block in a blob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of no way to query the maximum size on demand, but I believe the value you are looking for is stored as a constant in the .net SDK.
`Constants.MaxBlobSize` and `Constants.MaxBlockSize` in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol` namespace would be the values you are interested in.

```
/// <summary>
/// The maximum size of a blob with blocks.
/// </summary>
public const long MaxBlobSize = MaxBlockNumber * MaxBlockSize;
```

With MaxBlockSize being

```
/// <summary>
/// The maximum size of a single block for Block Blobs.
/// </summary>
public const int MaxBlockSize = (int)(100 * Constants.MB);
```

[Source (Constants.cs)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/25e44ab13389a45a644e445031988ce68cfbd7a6/Lib/Common/Shared/Protocol/Constants.cs#L82)

Answer (score 2):

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#writing-to-an-append-blob

> Each block in an append blob can be a different size, up to a maximum
>   of 4 MB, and an append blob can include a maximum of 50,000 blocks.
>   **The maximum size of an append blob is therefore slightly more than 195
>   GB (4 MB X 50,000 blocks)**.

Comment: This is true for append blobs, for normal blobs it's 50,000 X 100 MB as per https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/azure-storage-limits.md (and the code in Constants.cs)

Comment: @Brunner Thanks for the note.

Comment: Still does not answer the question. I need to retrieve them programmatically (preferably without parsing html content).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the maximum allowed size
> for an Azure Blob? Also for a block in a blob?

As of today, no. There's no programmatic way of retrieving this information. However this information is well published [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs) and it does not changes very often. Since 2008, I believe the size has changed only once and that too for block blobs.

Here're the limits as of today:

## Block Blobs

Max Size: 4.75 TB (if you use Service Version 2016-05-31 or greater)

Max Size: 195 GB (if you use Service Version prior to 2016-05-31)

Max Block Size: 100MB (if you use Service Version 2016-05-31 or greater)

Max Block Size: 4MB (if you use Service Version prior to 2016-05-31)

Max Number of Blocks: 50000

## Page Blobs

Max Size: 1TB

## Append Blobs

Max Size: 195GB

Max Block Size: 4MB

Max Number of Blocks: 50000

Comment: I know about these. I was just wondering whether there is any way to retrieve the in code.

Comment: The answer is no :).

Comment: Yes, there is, check correct answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: For all practical intents and purposes this would work but the fact remains that it is hardcoded in the SDK. There's no API to fetch this information (and hence my comment). So if Azure Storage team  change this limit (which does not happen very often), you would need to ensure that you're using the correct SDK.